# CQ aka AEM | Blueprints vs. Live copies

Tags: aem, blueprint

In cq we can create live copies by either `blueprints` by opting `"New Site..."` or directly trough content nodes by opting for `"New Live Copy..."`.

In both the cases `inheritance` is maintained and `roll-out` works too in same ways. So what is the advantage of using one over other.

Any views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Live Copies**

Live copies can be created for just a simple page or a tree of pages and might the page and it's subpages depending on the rollout configuration. A live copy can be linked to a rollout config or will use the system's default one.
There is no formal requirement on the source page's structure.
A live copy might reference a blueprint, while it can only reference to a single blueprint.

**Blueprints**

Blueprints target the rollout of complete multilingual website projects and are a tool to control multiple rollout configs and live copies.
A blueprint requires a certain structure for the source site:
- One root level page
- The root's immediate childs define the language branches of the site
- each language contains one or more child pages.

Blueprints allow you to control multiple live copies and centrally  consistent rollout configs for the blueprint's live copies.
A blueprint rollout will push modifications to all it's live copies.

**Usage scenarios of blueprints**

Inheritance and rollout work the same way. Just because blueprint make use of live copies. 
But blueprints help you to organize your rollout scenarios for large multilingual sites. Just imagine a corporate website that provides a two or even three digit number of locales which that need to be translated and kept in sync.
In such a scenario you will likely end up with a hardly understandable and maintainable number of live copy and rollout configurations.
Depending on a blueprint to e.g. standardize the rollout of a new language/market/locale provides you higher degree of governance over your process as the complete process centrally manageable through the blueprint template.

But as long as you do not have such a scenario you might be fine without having the complete blueprint overhead.

Answer (score 0):

A Livecopy is defined in the target page node with a cq:LiveSyncConfig node. It basically defines: I am a livecopy of source (blueprint) page X, and the following rollout configs apply.

A Blueprint is defined in the source page node with a cq:BlueprintSyncConfig node, and this defines a target.

Essentially both achieve the same in the end, but I think there are a few differences: the first option can be used to create a 1:n relationship, whereas the second option is 1:1

Also, if page nodes are copy-pasted in AEM, then relationships are copied with them (not quite sure in which way exactly, you would have to try for both scenarios). Also when pages are deleted in a tree in the first scenario, AEM will add a cq:excludedPaths property to the config which causes the page to be skipped in future rollouts - not sure this is the same for cq:BlueprintSyncConfig as well.