# AEM | Difference between Live Copy and BluePrint

Tags: aem

Please provide details about the difference between creating a live copies from blueprint and live copies directly(New-> New Live Copy) with scenarios/examples, in AEM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CQ aka AEM | Blueprints vs. Live copies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237029/cq-aka-aem-blueprints-vs-live-copies)

Answer (score 3):

**Blueprint**: Is the basic structure created as a copy of existing site. Ex: We have a requirement to create a site with the same structure as Geometrixx site, we can create a Blueprint for the new site providing the Source Path attribute as Geometrixx site path.

**Live Copy**: Is  basically creating a new site based on the content and structure of an existing site or blueprint so that when changes are made in base/source site, it is automatically updated here.
i.e. Create a livecopy and enter the source page as “Geometrixx/Global/English”.
So any update to the ‘Geometrixx/Global/English’ page automatically updates the livecopy page.

**Rollout**: Using blueprint rollout feature we can push modifications to all it’s live copies simultaneously.